# Looking up all keys in a hashmap like data structure that are a subset of a query

Tags: algorithm, hashmap

## The Question

Let's say I have a HashMap:

```
{
  "foo" => (A,B),
  "bar" => (B,C),
  "baz" => (A,D)
}
```

And I transform it into some other data-structure, something similar to:

```
{
  (A,B) => "foo",
  (B,C) => "bar",
  (A,D) => "baz",
  (D,E) => "biz"
}
```

Given the 'key' (or query I suppose): `(A,B,C)`

I'd like to lookup all values where their key is a subset of the query set: `("foo","bar")`

I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm/data-structure that will do that lookup efficiently, although I don't think there's a O(1) solution.

## One possible solution

One idea I had was to break up the transformed map to look like this:

```
{
  A => ("foo","baz"),
  B => ("foo","bar")
  C => ("bar"),
  D => ("baz","biz"),
  E => ("biz")
}
```

Then lookup each element **not** in the query set: `(D => ("baz", "biz"), E => ("biz"))`

Union them: `("baz", "biz")`

And take the difference from the set of all possible results: `("foo", "bar", "baz", "biz") - ("baz", "biz") => ("foo", "bar")`

While this works, it's a lot of steps with an num_of_set_elements number of unions, and on large sets with a small query, a possibly huge number of lookups.

So, does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Please provide the constraints: how many keys `A,B,C` do you expect, entries `(A,B) => "foo"`, queries `(A,B,C)`, and what are you optimizing for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution does not need to build a new structure: iterate through the pairs (key, value) and if the value is a subset of your target, yield the key. The expected time is O(n) (n = number of keys) if you can represent the sets with a 64 bits integer (less than 64 atomic values `A`, `B`, `C`, ...). See https://cs.calvin.edu/activities/books/c++/ds/2e/WebItems/Chapter09/Bitsets.pdf for example (S contains A if A & S == S), and more if you have to check the potential subsets another way.

But if you have enough room and a long time for preprocessing data, there's a (crazy?) amortized O(1) time solution for lookup.
If `S` is the set of all possible atomic values (`A`, `B`, ...), you can build all the possible supersets of every value (`(A, B)`, `(A, C)`, ...) that are subsets of `S`.
Now you can build a new map like this (pseudocode):

```
for each pair (key, value):
    for every superset s of value:
        add key to m[s]
```

The lookup will be in constant amortized time O(1). The map will have roughly `2^|S|` keys. The size of the values will depend on the size of the keys, e.g. the biggest key, `S`, will contain every key of the initial map. Preprocessing will be something like O(n*2^|S|).

I'd rather go for O(n) though.